# Why can't I play audio from two or more sources?

Tags: linux, audio, debian, alsa

When I installed on my desktop mpd and mpc, I found that I can't hear other sources (like Amarok, Flash player etc.) at the time when mpc or other client is playing music. If I try to start an audio stream with two Flash players in two tabs, I have the same problem.

How to solve it?
I have installed PulseAudio with default system settings and Jackd. How do I configure it for multiple sound sources?

> gigam@bird:~$ aplay -l
>   List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices
>   card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], device 0: ALC888 Analog [ALC888 Analog]
>   Subdevices: 1/1
>   Subdevice #0: subdevice #0 
>   card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], device 1: ALC888 Digital [ALC888 Digital]
>   Subdevices: 1/1
>   Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
>   card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
>   Subdevices: 1/1
>   Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
>   card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 7: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
>   Subdevices: 1/1
>   Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
>   card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 8: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
>   Subdevices: 1/1
>   Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
>   card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 9: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
>   Subdevices: 1/1
>   Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

I'm using ALSA and PulseAudio as it was installed automatically.

P.S.
Hmmm... I have one additional error from PulseAudio:
pacmd:

> >> load-module module-alsa-sink
>   Module load failed.

But in directory "/usr/lib/pulse-2.0/modules" I have it:
module-alsa-sink.so

Comment: I mean music and Skype alerts, for example, at one time. It's impossible in my system now. And it's not an answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Try the solution posted [here](http://forum.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=197&t=58616&sid=6a23a5aa97062bbe553f3ccfc821268a). Add these lines to /etc/asound.conf:

```
pcm.pulse {
    type pulse
}
ctl.pulse {
    type pulse
}
pcm.!default {
    type pulse
}
ctl.!default {
    type pulse
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The actual problem you're having is that -- probably -- `mpd` is configured to use ALSA by default. Did you know that `mpd` has a PulseAudio backend? Look at `/etc/mpd.conf`.

Anyway, `mpd` and `mpc` is a silly way to play music if you're just doing it locally. `mpd` is really designed for network streaming, like to run a streaming radio station. There are many other programs that will use PulseAudio natively, such as Rhythmbox, which requires zero configuration.

@terdon's answer should help if you have programs that are using the `Safe ALSA Subset` and respect libasound2 plug-layer configuration. But if any one program tries to open `hw:0` or a similar direct-to-hardware ALSA device, it will prevent PulseAudio from working properly, and will block out all other access to the sound device.

I also don't know why you are trying to use `jackd`, since that is normally only for high-end audio work such as in Digital Audio Workstations (DAWs). Installing it probably didn't activate it (fortunately) or you'd have an even bigger mess.

A few things about your post make me think that you are making this **entirely too difficult**:

- You "installed" PulseAudio. Why wasn't it installed by default?
- You "installed" `jackd`. What made you think that doing that would be a good idea? Do you need to run a program that **only** runs on JACK, such as Ardour2?
- You seem to need to play with configuration files such as `/etc/asound.conf`. This really should not be necessary.

It sounds like you are trying to run an extremely, extremely old version of Debian. Honestly, any distribution that is not from **at least** 2011 (and Debian Squeeze doesn't count) is not going to have a good out-of-the-box audio experience. My recommendation is to go with the latest stable release of Ubuntu, Linux Mint, OpenSUSE, or Fedora.

Old versions of Debian (and other distros, too) have a very poor out of the box audio experience, where things don't "just work" and have to be manually configured. So the fact that you had to **install** PulseAudio, when it has been shipped and enabled by default on distros since 2008, tells me you are running an *ancient* OS. It's free; you should upgrade rather than trying to manually re-do what distributions have done flawlessly through a lot of research and development over the past 5 years.